# Can't search in shared folder after I use NetworkConnection class

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, file-sharing

I hit a wall when trying to `fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories` from a share folder after using a `new NetworkConnection(path, credentials)`.

I'm using the `NetworkConnection.cs` from [this](https://gist.github.com/AlanBarber/92db36339a129b94b7dd). The call of the `new NetworkConnection(path, credentials)` works fine, I get `result = 0`.
 But when the `fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories` executes I get a `Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 8802.3403ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () [https://localhost:44373/Materials/GetFiles?MCodeID=24140.00]`

The full code of `~/Materials/GetFiles` is:

```cs
public JsonResult GetFiles(string MCodeID)
{
  if (MCodeID == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MCodeID));
  }

  List<Files> filelist = new List<Files>();
  string path = @"\\192.168.1.191\Materials Project";
  string searchPattern = MCodeID + "*";
  var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain");
  using (new NetworkConnection(path, credentials))
  {
    DirectoryInfo fi = new DirectoryInfo(path + '\\');
    if (fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())
    {
      foreach (var file in fi.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
      {
        var changeSlash = file.FullName.Replace('\\', '/');
        var nfilepath = changeSlash.Replace("//192.168.1.191/Materials Project", "");
        filelist.Add(new Files
        {
          FCodeID = nfilepath,
          FDescr = file.Name + " | " + Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(file.Length) / (1024 * 1024)), 2) + " MB",
        });
      }
      filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = "0", FDescr = "--Select File--" });
    }
    else
    {
      filelist.Insert(0, new Files { FCodeID = "0", FDescr = "--No File--" });
    }
  }
  return Json(new SelectList(filelist, "FCodeID", "FDescr"));
}
```

What I'm a missing?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above error by providing a user with full access to the share folder and not just read permission.